# Is there a function in SQL that returns 1 row where the datediff = min for each Campaign?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to return one row per campaign where the DATEDIFF between Response and Assignment = MIN(DATEDIFF).

Here's the query I have so far:

```
;WITH Responses AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Marketing_Daily_summary_keymetrics_withoutPOI] r 
    WHERE [Total Responses] = 1
)

,

Assignments AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [Salesforce].[dbo].[n2de__Distribution_log__c] DL 
)

SELECT
     Responses.[Campaign Name]
    ,Responses.[Date]
    ,Assignments.[n2de__Assignment_date__c]
    ,DATEDIFF(hour,Responses.[Date],Assignments.[n2de__Assignment_date__c]) 'Hours between Response and Assignment'
    ,MIN(DATEDIFF(hour,Responses.[Date],Assignments.[n2de__Assignment_date__c])) 'MIN Hours between Response and Assignment' 
    
    

FROM Responses
LEFT JOIN Assignments
        ON Responses.[Lead/Contact id] = COALESCE(Assignments.[n2de__Contact__c],Assignments.[n2de__Lead__c]) 
                                         AND (Assignments.[n2de__Assignment_date__c] >= Responses.[Date]
                                            OR Assignments.[n2de__Assignment_date__c]  IS NULL)

WHERE Responses.[Lead/Contact id] = '00Q5a00001sbhnkEAA'
AND Responses.[Campaign Name] IN ('Campaign A', 'Campaign B', 'Campaign C')


GROUP BY 
     Responses.[Campaign Name]
    ,Responses.[Date]
    ,Assignments.[n2de__Assignment_date__c]
```

...which generates this table...

| Campaign Name | Date | n2de__Assignment_date__c | Hours between Response and Assignment | MIN Hours between Response and Assignment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign A | 5/18/21 2:35 PM | 5/18/21 3:06 PM | 1 | 1 |
| Campaign A | 5/18/21 2:35 PM | 5/19/21 3:26 PM | 25 | 25 |
| Campaign A | 5/18/21 2:35 PM | 5/25/21 3:00 PM | 169 | 169 |
| Campaign A | 5/18/21 2:35 PM | 6/1/21 5:43 PM | 339 | 339 |
| Campaign B | 5/7/21 2:09 PM | 5/7/21 2:57 PM | 0 | 0 |
| Campaign B | 5/7/21 2:09 PM | 5/11/21 3:44 PM | 97 | 97 |
| Campaign B | 5/7/21 2:09 PM | 5/18/21 3:06 PM | 265 | 265 |
| Campaign B | 5/7/21 2:09 PM | 5/19/21 3:26 PM | 289 | 289 |
| Campaign B | 5/7/21 2:09 PM | 5/25/21 3:00 PM | 433 | 433 |
| Campaign B | 5/7/21 2:09 PM | 6/1/21 5:43 PM | 603 | 603 |
| Campaign C | 4/29/21 4:35 PM | 4/29/21 8:34 PM | 4 | 4 |
| Campaign C | 4/29/21 4:35 PM | 5/7/21 2:57 PM | 190 | 190 |
| Campaign C | 4/29/21 4:35 PM | 5/11/21 3:44 PM | 287 | 287 |
| Campaign C | 4/29/21 4:35 PM | 5/18/21 3:06 PM | 455 | 455 |
| Campaign C | 4/29/21 4:35 PM | 5/19/21 3:26 PM | 479 | 479 |
| Campaign C | 4/29/21 4:35 PM | 5/25/21 3:00 PM | 623 | 623 |
| Campaign C | 4/29/21 4:35 PM | 6/1/21 5:43 PM | 793 | 793 |

The desired output looks like this:

| Campaign Name | Date | n2de__Assignment_date__c | Hours between Response and Assignment | MIN Hours between Response and Assignment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign A | 5/18/21 2:35 PM | 5/18/21 3:06 PM | 1 | 1 |
| Campaign B | 5/7/21 2:09 PM | 5/7/21 2:57 PM | 0 | 0 |
| Campaign C | 4/29/21 4:35 PM | 4/29/21 8:34 PM | 4 | 4 |

Comment: you could put the last ```select``` in another```cte``` and then select the rows which correspond to the ```min``` criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` window function plus SQL Server's `TOP(1) WITH TIES .. ORDER BY` feature

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
     r.[Campaign Name]
    ,r.[Date]
    ,a.[n2de__Assignment_date__c]
    ,DATEDIFF(hour, r.[Date], a.[n2de__Assignment_date__c]) [Min Hours between Response and Assignment]
FROM Responses r 
LEFT JOIN Assignments a
        ON r.[Lead/Contact id] = COALESCE(a.[n2de__Contact__c], a.[n2de__Lead__c]) 
            AND (a.[n2de__Assignment_date__c] >= r.[Date]
                 OR a.[n2de__Assignment_date__c]  IS NULL)    
WHERE r.[Lead/Contact id] = '00Q5a00001sbhnkEAA'
      AND r.[Campaign Name] IN ('Campaign A', 'Campaign B', 'Campaign C')       
ORDER BY row_number() over(partition by r.[Campaign Name] order by DATEDIFF(hour, r.[Date], a.[n2de__Assignment_date__c]))
```